# How to change sonata admin bundle Group Permission names?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using sonata admin bundle for my project. I cannot find how do I assign a readable name to the Group Permissions names. At the moment is shows as key value.

```
 [0 => ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ISSUE_CREATE] [1 => ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_STATUS_DELETE] [2 => ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST] [3 => ROLE_ADMIN] [4 => ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
```

This is a screenshot of it.
[image: Sonata Admin Preview]

[Large Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5to0M.jpg)

How do I add a human friendly names to these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roles field is an array. by default the SonataAdminBundle render the array as you see. If you want another type of rendering you can extends the admin as described here : http://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/extensions.html

Then you can define a custom template to render the roles field.